# Pronunciation question: bisuketto ビスケット

Tags: pronunciation

When I hear bisuketto pronounced I hear bisket-to. I don't hear bisuket-to. Is it my ears or do you just not say su? If not, why not? Is there a pronunciation rule I'm not aware of maybe?

Comment: Duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1095/25413 ?

Comment: ^ 何で「ワンワン」が出てくるのかわかんないんですけど・・・。「～です。」、「～ます。」が "des", "mas" になる、 [母音の無声化](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/日本語の音韻#.E6.AF.8D.E9.9F.B3.E3.81.AE.E7.84.A1.E5.A3.B0.E5.8C.96)([Devoicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#Devoicing))の話でしょ・・

Comment: Related question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5175/9831

Comment: The articles above are useful but they fail to mention it's only a feature seen in some eastern dialects including Tokyo and not all the native speakers speak this way. Variation of pronunciation itself has nothing to do with Standard Japanese either, which is defined with grammar and vocabulary, not pronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a rule about this like you shouldn't pronounce u at the end of ます.It is just that when it is pronounced fast it sounds like bisketto and they don't especially try to pronounce the letter u there.