# Is dropping u in ですね/ですよ a special case?

Tags: pronunciation

So I never though about it, but ですね and ですよ don't follow the silent vowel rules, but I don't think I've ever heard (desu ne) or (desu yo). It's always (des ne) and (des yo). Unless I'm imagining things, is this right? Is this some special case? Or is the u actually said with ね and よ?

Comment: The u in です is typically devoiced and pronounced as "des" and the same goes for ですね/ですよ. Of course, there are exceptions such dialects, emphasis, and feminine speech.

Comment: @Infenoboy please link to or describe the rules you're referring to, or it will be difficult for answerers to know what you're thinking of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Actual phonetic realization of "devoiced" vowels](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1904/actual-phonetic-realization-of-devoiced-vowels)