# In compound words what is it called when two Ks assimilate into a っ?

Tags: readings, gemination, onyomi

Eg. 厄介、欲求、直径、即興、却下、借金、引っ越す、北海道、積極、薬局

Wouldn't っ normally require the first onyomi to have a tsu ending?

Why doesn't it happen in certain words like 加湿器?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Wouldn't っ normally require the first onyomi to have a tsu ending?*

No. This small っ is unrelated to big つ in most cases. This letter is used as *gemination* ([促音【そくおん】](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokuon)) *marker* that you should double the *next* consonant<sup>*1</sup>.

One source of geminate consonants is kanji that had final consonant accommodated to Japanese pronunciation<sup>*2</sup> e.g. 合 *kap* + 戦 *sen* → 合戦 *ka**ss**en*, 鉄 *tet* + 器 *ki* → 鉄器 *te**kk**i* etc. Another is reduction of sound in some conjugation forms e.g. 勝ちて *ka**ti**te* → 勝って *ka**t**te*, ありたり *a**ri**tari* → あった *a**t**ta* etc. In the latter case, typical examples are followed by *t*, and that's why つ (Classical pronunciation *tu*) was chosen as symbol of gemination.

Until WWII, both the gemination sign and syllable *tsu* were just being written in big つ, which made a handful of confusion such as カミツレ ("chamomile"; misreading of カミッレ (Dutch *Kamille*)) or カムチャッカ (Kamchatka; misreading of カムチャツカ). In post-war orthography, we can safely distinguish ordinary つ and geminate っ.

> *Why doesn't it happen in certain words like 加湿器?*

Because, "natural" assimilation of consonants hardly happens based on today's pronunciation. Kanji that originally had final consonant have turned into open syllable (塔 *ta**p*** → *to**u***, 鉄 *te**t*** → *te**tsu***, 悪 *a**k*** → *a**ku*** etc.) thus there aren't any more chances two consonants come together. The gemination becomes more like conventional rule when you put two or more kanji to make a word. In this case, 加湿 is already a word, so no gemination happens between 加湿 and 器.

That said, the phenomenon is still productive between kanji that have final `-ku` and initial `k-`<sup>*3</sup>. Famous examples include 洗濯機 (せんたっき < せんたくき), 水族館 (すいぞっかん < すいぞくかん). Theoretically kanji that end with `-tsu` could trigger the same effect, but the problem is we don't have many words start with `ts-` (豪雪地帯【ごうせつちたい】 *might* be pronounced like ごうせっちたい).

Further reading: [第7期 (1964-1965) 国語審議会：発音のゆれについて（部会報告）](http://kokugo.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/joho/kakuki/07/tosin03/)

---

<sup>*1: Sometimes it doesn't have a consonant following it in modern usage. In this case it represents a [glottal stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop).</sup>

<sup>*2: Incidentally, [Italians did the same thing](https://damyanlissitchkov.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/how-latin-became-italian/): Latin octo ‘eight’ > otto, Latin maximus ‘greatest’ > massimo etc.</sup>

<sup>*3: The reason is usually attributed to so-called ["vowel devoicing"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1095/7810) that virtually eliminate the vowel under certain conditions, cf. すこし > [skosh](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skosh).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The name of this phenomenon is called "gemination," and it is a specific case of a larger phenomenon that happens in many languages called "sandhi" (after some research, there appears to be a Japanese term for this as well, known as 連{れん}音{おん}).

As for why it doesn't happen in 加湿器, I actually am not 100% sure myself, but I would guess it's because Japanese usually resists these kinds of changes when looking at the second pair when more than 2 things are being combined. At least that's the case for rendaku, but maybe someone could shed some more light on this?

Comment: "連音" >>[促音便](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF#.E4.BF.83.E9.9F.B3.E4.BE.BF)ではなく・・・？

Comment: @chocolate As I understood it, 連音 describes sandhi in general, whereas 促音便 is a term for this specific case, but, again, please feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: @chocolate 「促音便」は促音を使った音便のことで、和語の音変化にしか使わないと思います（ぶっとばす、など）。漢語の方は特に名前がなくて「促音化」としかいえない（？）気がします。

Answer (score 0):

I think in general this happens to ease pronunciation, so a word isn't too hard to pronounce then generally it doesn't have to change. I think I've heard of variations based on modern / past or dialect.

This for example doesn't even have to a 'k' sound or a 'big つ' initially, even words like 暖かい (あたたかい) are very commonly pronounced (あったかい), ta-ta-ka is naturally simplified to っ-ta-ka