# Why was つ originally used to mark consonant gemination? When was that?

Tags: history, orthography, kana, gemination

I can't find the answer anywhere.

It seems that in manyougana consonant gemination was not marked in any way. And before the 1946 reform the normal size つ　was used instead of the current smaller one. But what was the original reason to start using つ as the consonant doubling symbol, and not say く or some original symbol altogether?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33730/7810

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short summary:** Heian-period Japanese acquired new sounds, including a syllable-final *-t*, a geminated *tt*, and other geminated consonants. The つ kana, originally *tu*, was a natural match to write the new *-t*, which led to its use in *tt*, and from that it slowly became the symbol for gemination in general.

**Long answer:**

Nara-period Old Japanese had no long consonants.  This is why the writing system originally had no way of representing them, and was forced to coöpt some other symbol into the role.  (They *could* have created a new symbol—it seems that katakana ン was invented around the 11th century specifically to write the moraic nasal unambiguously—but people generally seem to prefer working with the symbols they already know; consider how English writing failed to create letters to denote all its new vowels, but just make do awkwardly with the five Latin basic vowel letters.)

In the transition to Heian-period Early Middle Japanese, some very significant sound changes occurred (the *onbin* changes).  They added, among other things, long vowels and consonants, and are the source of current verb forms like *motte* < *motite*. (For greater clarity, I will use *kunrei rōmaji* in this answer; つ = *tu*, ち = *ti*. Notice these sounds weren't originally pronounced as in Modern Japanese, but likely as in *ta*.)

Now that Japanese had become a moraic language, they had the problem of how to represent those new sounds.  They might just not represent them at all (e.g. *motte* written as モテ; 9th century).  Or they might use a number of different old *kana*—I don't have a listing of which ones, exactly, but there was overlap between them and also the new moraic nasal (now written ん); e.g. gemination could be written as 牟／ム, the usual symbol for the nasal (as if, in modern *kana*, you could write *motte* as もんて).

Around the same period, a second, distinct source of new sounds were Chinese loanwords—the ancestor of current *kango* (*on'yomi*)—and a lot of those ended with a syllable-final *-t* (as in e.g. 罰, modern Japanese *batu*, modern Cantonese  *fat*, Hakka *fat*; 達, J. *tatu*, Cantonese *daat/taat*; 日, J. *niti/jitu*, Cantonese *jat*, Hakka *ngit*, Hokkien *jit/lit/git*, and so on).  That these sounds were pronounced with a final *-t* consonant in Middle Japanese is clear from the descriptions left by the Jesuits in the 16th century, and also supported by reconstruction.

How was syllable-final *-t* represented in writing? As you might have guessed, by the *kana* symbols for *-tu* (or, sometimes, *-ti*).  Recall that in historical times there were several *kana* symbols for each sound (the variants now called *hentaigana*).  There's evidence that some texts consistently use some graphical variants for *-tu* and others for *-t*; but most texts just used an underspecified *-tu*, and you had to guess which sound was meant.

Since the *tu* symbols could denote a single *-t*, they were a natural choice for the first *t* in *tt*; *mo-t-te* = も.つ.て.  By extension, つ came to be the generic symbol of gemination for other consonants (cf. the case of ム above).  All this dates from Heian, but was quite in a state of flux for a long time, and consolidated slowly.  There's probably no sharp line for when did all geminates could be said to always and consistently be marked by つ; both sources for this answer only say it "spread gradually" and was settled "relatively late".  The syllable-final *-t*, too, only became *-ti* and *-tu* quite recently (historically speaking).

Sources:

- Frellesvig, *A History of the Japanese Language*
- 『日本国語大辞典』, apud [Japanese wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%A3).