# What is the middle character in Todd (Katakana)

Tags: translation, katakana, names, orthography, gemination

While learning Katakana, I was instructed to try and translate my name Todd. I ended up with トド.

When I look it up online, I see トッド everywhere. ッ appears to be 'tsu'.

I think I am missing something about combined characters. Can anyone provide some clarification?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did "little tsu" become a lengthener?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/751/how-did-little-tsu-become-a-lengthener)

Comment: Also related [In compound words what is it called when two Ks assimilate into a っ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33730/11792) and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "small *tsu*" ッ is not pronounced *tsu*, but rather represents [gemination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination).

The rule of thumb is that a final D gets transliterated as ッド (and a final T as ット)

- bed → ベッド
- pad → パッド
- good → グッド
- god → ゴッド

As you probably learned, this is part of a set of rules of thumb, which deal with final consonants in transliteration, since (except for ン) there are no *kana* without a vowel at the end.

As Japanese phonetics allow for /u/ to be almost silent, naturally *kana* from the /-u/-column in the *kana* chart (e.g. ク, ス, フ, etc.) would be good candidates to simulate final consonants. However, for /du/ or /tu/ this does not work, as these are pronounced *zu* and *tsu* and so here one uses the *kana* from the /-o/-column instead.

I guess the small *tsu* ッ is added to make the ド sound more "dry", i.e. more like a consonant and less like a syllable.

See also

- [How did "little tsu" become a lengthener?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/751/1628)
- [Why was つ originally used to mark consonant gemination? When was that?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39312/1628)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and links. I appreciate it!