# Why is 学校 pronounced as "gakkou" and not "gakukou"

Tags: pronunciation, language-change

There's only one onyomi reading for kanji 学 and its "gaku", where did "gatsu" come from?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33730/7810

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically, 学校 was spelled in kana -- and pronounced as something like -- がくかう.  Regular sound changes resulted in modern がっこう:

- In the ～くか～ in the middle, the //u// sound was unstressed, leading to it gradually being omitted.
- The //au// vowel combination on the end shifted from //au// (like English *ow!*) to //ɔː// (like English *awe*) by the early 1600s, as demonstrated by the 1603 [*Nippo Jisho*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nippo_Jisho) (Japanese-Portuguese dictionary).  This then merged with //oː// (the long "O" sound) between then and the early modern period.

Comment: So, is it the same as ateji?

Comment: @Kanpie No.  It's not *ateji*.  This is a regular and nearly predictable sound change.

Comment: @Kanpie It seems it's almost a rule that in a two-mora *on*-reading that ends in either き or く followed by another *on*-reading beginning with *k*, there will be gemmation.  I believe there are exceptions, but I think the exceptions are fairly rare.

Comment: @Kanpie, as A.Ellett notes, this is a regular sound change. If you think about it, two //k// sounds in quick succession aren't always easy to clearly pronounce, so this kind of phonological contraction is unsurprising. Separately, _ateji_ refers only to spelling. The word is literally _ate_ (from 当てる【あてる】, "to apply something against something else") + 字【じ】 ("character"): most specifically, when a kanji **character** is **applied** to a spelling solely for its sound value, ignoring its meaning.  Things like using 四六四九 to spell よろしく, or using ３９ to spell サンキュー.