# Is かぐや姫 pronounced "Ka-gu-ya" or "Kag'-ya"?

Tags: pronunciation

皆さん、こんばんは！

Just a quick question. Is かぐや姫's name pronounced "Kaguya" or "Kag'ya"?
aka. Is the う dropped or not?

Just curious as I haven't found a definitive answer for this yet.

Comment: Vowels are never dropped following voiced sounds.

Comment: Related: [What are the rules regarding "mute vowels" ("u" after "s" and "i" after "sh")?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1095/542)

Comment: I don't see う posted in the question or the message body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Japanese teacher taught me a trick which now I use as a rule of thumb (there may be exceptions but it works most of the time). Just say it both ways and look at the phonics of the following consonant.

*Kag-ya*, or *Ka-gya* (when dropping the vowel, is more like かっぎゃ/カッギャ)

has a very different pronunciation to

*ka-gu-ya*

Specifically, *-ya* leads from a *e* (the shape you mouth makes when it starts to say *e*). Therefore it shouldn't (cannot) be dropped.

In my experience, one never has to drop the vowel in proper nouns (e.g. names) unless it's a nuance of the name. Japanese names, in particular, tend to favour enunciation of each syllable.

One last thing to remember is that, in a particular dialect, contraction may happen but more often than not, there is nothing wrong with enunciating each syllable.